# Paypal smart buttons pay with balance no longer works

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm facing a new behaviour with paypal smart buttons, the pay with balance button no longer works, became unclickable, no pop up at all, I've changed nothing ^, it stopped working some day in production and with sandbox, the pay with credit card still works.

Here is the code :

```
try {
      const FUNDING_SOURCES = [
        paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
        paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT,
        paypal.FUNDING.CARD
      ];
    
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          size: 'small',
          color: 'gold',
          shape: 'pill',
          label: 'checkout'
        },
        funding: {
          allowed: FUNDING_SOURCES
        },
        onInit: (data, actions) => {
          this.logger.log('=====> PAYPAL onInit');
          actions.enable();
        },
        onCancel: (data) => {
          this.logger.log('=====> PAYPAL onCancel');
          return;
        },
        createOrder: async (data: any, actions: any) => {
          return await actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                reference_id: params.order.orderID,
                description: 'Order ID : ' + params.order.orderID,
                amount: {
                  currency_code: params.currency,
                  value: params.order.finalTotal,

                },
                breakdown: {
                  item_total: {
                    currency_code: params.currency,
                    value: params.order.total
                  },
                  shipping: {
                    currency_code: params.currency,
                    value: params.order.orderDelivery.cost
                  }
                },
                shipping: {
                  method: params.order.orderDelivery.mode.code,
                  address: {
                    name: {
                      full_name: fullName
                    },
                    address_line_1: address1,
                    address_line_2: address2,
                    admin_area_1: city,
                    admin_area_2: country.name,
                    postal_code:  zipcode,
                    country_code: country.code2
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          });
        },
       
        onApprove: async (data: any, actions: any) => {
          const order = await actions.order;
          order.capture().then((details: any) => {
            // the capture logic here ommited

            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
          });
        },
        onError: (err: any) => {
           // the error mgmt logic here ommited

        }
      }).render('#paypalContainer').then(() => {
        params.paymentModeLoaded = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.log('===> Error Loading paypal buttons \n' + e);
    }
```

I read that it could be related to country of connection but I tried with multiple European countries (using VPN) with no luck

Thanks

Comment: Assign whatever is in `actions.order.create(...)` to a variable, log it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(varname,null,2))` and update your question with this information

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply , the button is not even clickable , so actions.order.create is not called , but i got a weird behaviour while testing , i clicked on credit card , then i closed the popup , and clicked multiple times on paypal (pay with balance) buttons , then the popup is opened , the behaviour is random, clicking directly does not work , the output was {
  "resolved": false,
  "rejected": false,
  "errorHandled": false,
  "handlers": []
}

Comment: Works fine as far as I can tell without the create details. Maybe get rid of your onInit function since it is not doing anything

Comment: my bad ! it works , the problem i was testing with chrome mobile view , if i switch to desktop it just works , i always test in development with the mobile chrome view , then use iphone and android emulators and it works always , this time the paypal button does not trigger in chrome mobile view. Thank you for your attention.